# Play 2.4 JPA/Hibernate EntityManager does no flush to database

Tags: playframework, guice, jpa-2.1, playframework-2.4

I started a simple JPA-based Play 2.4 project und I have some problems to understand the correct usage of Play's EntityManager in a layered architecture, specially in the case of writing entities to the database. I'm a beginner in Play, usually I use Spring for Application development and barely worked with the entitymanager directly.

Lets say I have a controller for registering new users. To separate concerns, the controller just takes the request, delegates the request to the underlying service and returns the result, the newly created Registration entity in my example:

```
public class ApiController extends Controller {

    private final RegistrationService registrationService;

    @Inject
    public ApiController(final RegistrationService registrationService) {
        this.registrationService = registrationService;
    }

    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    @Transactional
    public Result startRegistration() {
        final JsonNode requestBody = request().body().asJson();
        final RegistrationRequest registrationRequest = Json.fromJson(requestBody, RegistrationRequest.class);
        final Registration result = registrationService.startRegistration(registrationRequest);
        return ok(Json.toJson(result));
    }
}
```

My Guice module, that binds my dependencies and provides the entity manager so I can inject it into my service:

```
public class RegistrationModule extends AbstractModule {

    protected void configure() {
        bind(TokenGenerator.class).to(TokenGeneratorSupport.class);
        bind(RegistrationService.class).to(RegistrationServiceSupport.class);
    }

    @Provides
    public EntityManager provideEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = JPA.em("default");
        LOG.info("Created EntityManager: {}", em);
        return em;
    }

    @Provides
    public Validator provideValidator() {
        final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        final Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
        return validator;
}
```

My service layer, that performs the db operations:

```
public abstract class DefaultJpaServiceSupport<T extends AbstractJpaEntity> implements BaseService<T> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;
    private final Validator validator;
    private final Class<T> type;

    protected DefaultJpaServiceSupport(final EntityManager entityManager, final Validator validator,
                                   final Class<T> type) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.validator = validator;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<T> getByUuid(final UUID uuid) {
        ...
        final TypedQuery<T> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString, getType());
        ...
        return entity;
    }

    protected final EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
}

public class RegistrationServiceSupport extends DefaultJpaServiceSupport<Registration>
    implements RegistrationService {

    private static final Logger.ALogger LOG = Logger.of(RegistrationServiceSupport.class);

    private final TokenGenerator tokenGenerator;

    @Inject
    protected RegistrationServiceSupport(final EntityManager entityManager, final Validator validator,
                                     final TokenGenerator tokenGenerator) {
        super(entityManager, validator, Registration.class);
        this.tokenGenerator = tokenGenerator;
    }

    @Override
    public Registration startRegistration(final RegistrationRequest request) {
    ...
        final Registration registration = getEntityManager().merge(new Registration.Builder(randomUUID(), request.getEmail(),
            request.getPassword(), tokenGenerator.generate()).build());

        return registration;
    }
} 
}
```

And here is the problem, getEntityManager().merge(..) doesn't write to my db, but my @PrePersist annotated methods are invoked, but there is no flush. The reader methods work fine with getEntityManager(). I already tried to wrap the merge(..) with JPA.withTransaction(...), but it makes no difference.

But when I change it to JPA.em().merge(..), it works as it should, the entity is written to db. 
But then, I have an ugly dependency to Play in my service, what I really wanted to avoid, thats why I provide the entitymanager it in the Module for dependency injection.

Maybe there is a problem in my design I can't see, but it is driven by my experiences in spring.

Every idea is really appreciated, I'm really stuck on this, and couldn't find any ideas elsewhere, the Play documentation wasn't helpful in this case as well.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `JPA.em("default")` creates new EntityManager not getting opened one.

Only calling `JPA.em()` will get current EntityManager created with `@Transactional` which has opened transaction and will flush on call end.

You could set name of `EntityManager` in `@Transactional`.

If you need to specify name in Module, the only solution is to wrap body of method `RegistrationServiceSupport.startRegistration` in JPA transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I recognized that a need this call of JPA.em(), instead of using getEntityManager(), that returns the injected entitymanager from my base service.